# Add dynamic content block to nav section generated by custom walker

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I am working on a theme that requires a piece of dynamic content nested in the navigation.  I'm using a custom walker to generate the menu. I need a way to add markup to the code that will be editable on the back end (probably ACF, not important).

The content will nest inside a specific section of the menu ("Products").  Not sure how to approach this with the custom walker.

The walker:

```
class Custom_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

        $default_classes = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

        $custom_classes = (array)get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_classes', true );

        // Is this a top-level menu item?
        if ($depth == 0)
            $custom_classes[] = 'menu-item-top-level';

        // Does this menu item have children?
        if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $default_classes))
            $custom_classes[] = 'menu-item-has-children';

        // Is this menu item active? (Top level only)
        $active_classes = array('current-menu-item', 'current-menu-parent', 'current-menu-ancestor', 'current_page_item', 'current-page-parent', 'current-page-ancestor');
        if ($depth == 0 && array_intersect($default_classes, $active_classes))
            $custom_classes[] = 'menu-item-active';

        // Give menu item a class based on its level/depth
        $level = $depth + 1;
        if ($depth > 0)
            $custom_classes[] = "menu-item-level-$level";

        $classes = join(' ', $custom_classes);

        ! empty ( $classes )
            and $classes = ' class="'. trim(esc_attr( $classes )) . '"';

        $output .= "<li $classes>";

        $attributes  = '';

        ! empty( $item->attr_title )
            and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->target )
            and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->xfn )
            and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->url )
            and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        $item_output = $args->before
            . "<a $attributes>"
            . $args->link_before
            . $title
            . '</a> '
            . $args->link_after
            . $description
            . $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters(
            'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
        ,   $item_output
        ,   $item
        ,   $depth
        ,   $args
        );
    }
}
```

This is called in my markup like so:

```
<nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'main', 'walker' => new Custom_Nav_Walker )); ?>
</nav>
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The question is very vague

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  First post I've made here.  I'll try to be more descriptive in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thank you to Howdy_McGee for getting me pointed in the right direction.  I was able to use the codex to get me the rest of the way there.

What I wound up doing was adding the end_el() function to my custom walker and modifying the output based on the post ID.

```
function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    if ($item->object_id == 26)
        $output .="<li class=\"custom-content\">DYNAMIC CONTENT WILL GO HERE</li>";
   $output .= "</li>\n";
}
```

I was initially using the item ID but decided that was not at all reliable and decided that the post ID was less likely to change.  Using ACF, I'll drop the short code in place of "DYNAMIC CONTENT WILL GO HERE".

Thanks again for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your Navigation Walker you can just append to the `$output` like so:

```
$output .= apply_filters(
    'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
,   $item_output
,   $item
,   $depth
,   $args
);

// This is before the ending list item:
$output .= '<span>Inner Navigational Text</span>';
```

To get the post meta (I'm not familiar with ACF) you can use `$item->object_id` which will be the actual post ID (`$item->ID` is the navigation item ID, not the post ID).

IF you want to add the content into the actual link you'll have to pre-create your content block, store it in a variable (let's say `$navContent`), then you'll have to replace the current link with the following:

```
$item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s%6$s</a>%7$s',
    $args->before,
    $attributes,
    $args->link_before,
    apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
    $args->link_after,
    $navContent,
    $args->after
);
```

If you're familiar with `sprinf()` this will make sense but if not, it just replaces the %6$s with the 6th variable in the argument list. The `s` indicates that it's a string which is why you'll want to create your content block before hand.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a shot and get back to you.  Thanks so much!